# Инвертирование (переворот) элементов нечетных столбцов матрицы

Tags: python

Задача: Дана прямоугольная целочисленная матрица. Произвести инвертирование (переворот) элементов нечетных столбцов без использования дополнительного массива и затем сформировать новый одномерный массив, в который записать элементы матрицы, кратные 2.

Снизу мой код, к которому только я мог прийти (работает только для матрицы 3х3, а нужно, чтобы и для больших работал), остановился только на этапе разворота столбцов, не понимаю, как сделать этот разворот правильно:

```
def swap(a):
    n= len(a)
    for i in range(n):
        a[i][i], a[n-i-1][i] = a[n-i-1][i], a[i][i]

def show (a):
    for x in a:
        print (["{:2d}".format(i) for i in x])

from random import randint
n, m = 3,3
a= [[randint(1,100) for j in range(m)] for i in range(n)]

show(a)
swap(a)
print (*a,sep='\n')
```